# Scaling different dicom images for feature extraction

Tags: matlab, image-processing, scaling, image-scaling, image-segmentation

I am developing a brain tumor identification algo. I have worked that part out and now want to use neural network to predict the grade of tumor. For feature extraction, I am using different dicom images. Since different dicom image have different skull size, zoom level, etc I am confused how to scale all the images so that when I extract features such as **Angular Second Moment**, it is correctly scaled for both.

[I am adding two dicoms.](http://d-h.st/G8e)

Comment: The scales of the skull are different: because these images are from two different patients, or there is another reason? Beside that, why don't you scale the tumors after extracting them?

Comment: @Bentoy13 I know that they are from different patients, that's the problem. How should I scale tumors?

Comment: My suggestion would be to extract the tumor from the rest, and then scale it before compute image moments. Since you've already identify the tumor, maybe you can create a mask of it, and compute the moment only in this region.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Alright, I can do that and that's a good suggestion. Problem is consider two different brain MR, zoomed at different level, having same size 256*256. How would I scale it in that case? Is there any info in dicom regarding such property?

Comment: I don't know what can be embedded in dicoms. Maybe a zoom factor is stored there... I really don't understand all info which can be viewed with a hexa editor. If you have this property, a first rescale can be done; in all cases, you can resize the tumor to a fix size (for example, 100*100) and compute the image features on this new image.

Comment: generally dicom images also have the scaling factor which gives you the dimensions of the image in real world, multiplying the image coordinates with the scaling factor and then resizing would help

Comment: @Bharat Yes I too thought that but I can't seem to find that scaling factor. Can you help me in this regard. I have uploaded two images, perhaps you can see what I am missing.

Comment: You can open the images in Slicer http://download.slicer.org/, the spacing information can be seen on clicking the cube button/volume information. Image spacing, 0.509mm, 0.509mm, 7.500mm (x,y,z), origin, 104.68085622787mm, 126.44338750839mm, 20.79146575928mm. The other image is at an angle.